# I was wondering how I can create two searchable tables that are not affected by the same code

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

Below is the Javascript code for a [simple searchable table](https://github.com/roparz/Light-Javascript-Table-Filter). However I would like to create a second table on the same page that follows the same code but without being affected by the first table. When I just try to do this, I end up with two separate tables, however because they are both using the same function, whenever I search in the first table, that search criteria is automatically applied to the separate table underneath it. How can I solve this issue?

```js
(function(document) {
  'use strict';

  var LightTableFilter = (function(Arr) {

    var _input;

    function _onInputEvent(e) {
      _input = e.target;
      var tables = document.getElementsByClassName(_input.getAttribute('data-table'));
      Arr.forEach.call(tables, function(table) {
        Arr.forEach.call(table.tBodies, function(tbody) {
          Arr.forEach.call(tbody.rows, _filter);
        });
      });
    }

    function _filter(row) {
      var text = row.textContent.toLowerCase(),
        val = _input.value.toLowerCase();
      row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : 'table-row';
    }

    return {
      init: function() {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('light-table-filter');
        Arr.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
          input.oninput = _onInputEvent;
        });
      }
    };
  })(Array.prototype);

  document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
      LightTableFilter.init();
    }
  });

})(document);
```

```html
<section class="container">

<h2>Hotels</h2>

<input type="search" class="light-table-filter" data-table="order-table" placeholder="Filter">

<table class="order-table table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Hotel</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Beds</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Telephone</th>
      <th>Telefax</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Webpage</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>john.doe@gmail.com</td>
      <td>0123456789</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td>0123456789</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td>0123456789</td>
      <td>99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jane Vanda</td>
      <td>jane@vanda.org</td>
      <td>9876543210</td>
      <td>349</td>
      <td>0123456789</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td>0123456789</td>
      <td>99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alferd Penyworth</td>
      <td>alfred@batman.com</td>
      <td>6754328901</td>
      <td>199</td>
      <td>0123456789</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td>0123456789</td>
      <td>99</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</section>
```

Comment: Where is second table? can you tell exact requirement here?

Comment: And would you have two input fields as well?

Comment: I'm still going through this, but my first thought is that your problem is related to your closure.  When you return the init function, the remainder of your functionality only exists by virtue of its reference in the init function.  There only exists one copy of this code in the entire program, you're not creating a new instance of LightTableFilter every time you call .init().  May be some other way to do what you want, but this is the first thing that popped out at me.

Comment: @JohnHalbert No. The function works. Since it works on all instances of data-table, any new table with the same class will be processed by the script for any input with class light-table-filter

Comment: @mplungjan Actually looking at it it seems very simple.  He's calling the same filter on all tables in the code.  Here: ' Arr.forEach.call(tables, function(table) { Arr.forEach.call(table.tBodies, function(tbody) { Arr.forEach.call(tbody.rows, _filter); }); });'  It's a single input applied to multiple tables. It's possible to have multiple inputs but he stores the input currently being evaluated in _input, and uses that to get the value for val in the _filter function. I think that's where the problem is.

Comment: Yes, I solved it too. Just change the classname of the tables and the corresponding input attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change the class name of each table and change the corresponding data-table attribute of the input:

```
<input ... data-table="order-table1"...>

<table class="order-table1 table">


<input ... data-table="order-table2" ...>

<table class="order-table2 table">
```

like this

```js
(function(document) {
  'use strict';

  var LightTableFilter = (function(Arr) {

    var _input;

    function _onInputEvent(e) {
      _input = e.target;
      var tables = document.getElementsByClassName(_input.getAttribute('data-table'));
      Arr.forEach.call(tables, function(table) {
        Arr.forEach.call(table.tBodies, function(tbody) {
          Arr.forEach.call(tbody.rows, _filter);
        });
      });
    }

    function _filter(row) {
      var text = row.textContent.toLowerCase(),
        val = _input.value.toLowerCase();
      row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : 'table-row';
    }

    return {
      init: function() {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('light-table-filter');
        Arr.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
          input.oninput = _onInputEvent;
        });
      }
    };
  })(Array.prototype);

  document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
      LightTableFilter.init();
    }
  });

})(document);
```

```html
<section class="container">

<h2>Hotels</h2>

<input type="search" class="light-table-filter" data-table="order-table1" placeholder="Filter">

<table class="order-table1 table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Hotel</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Beds</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Telephone</th>
      <th>Telefax</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Webpage</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>john.doe@gmail.com</td>
      <td>0123456789</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td>0123456789</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td>0123456789</td>
      <td>99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jane Vanda</td>
      <td>jane@vanda.org</td>
      <td>9876543210</td>
      <td>349</td>
      <td>0123456789</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td>0123456789</td>
      <td>99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alferd Penyworth</td>
      <td>alfred@batman.com</td>
      <td>6754328901</td>
      <td>199</td>
      <td>0123456789</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td>0123456789</td>
      <td>99</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  
  <input type="search" class="light-table-filter" data-table="order-table2" placeholder="Filter">

<table class="order-table2 table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Hotel</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Beds</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Telephone</th>
      <th>Telefax</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Webpage</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>john.doe@gmail.com</td>
      <td>0123456789</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td>0123456789</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td>0123456789</td>
      <td>99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jane Vanda</td>
      <td>jane@vanda.org</td>
      <td>9876543210</td>
      <td>349</td>
      <td>0123456789</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td>0123456789</td>
      <td>99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alferd Penyworth</td>
      <td>alfred@batman.com</td>
      <td>6754328901</td>
      <td>199</td>
      <td>0123456789</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td>0123456789</td>
      <td>99</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help, but I believe this kind sir here has found the solution to my problem. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Nice script by the way. It is found here: https://github.com/roparz/Light-Javascript-Table-Filter